# django form ForeignKey as ForeignKey.name not an ForeignKey.id

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='company')
```

views.py

```
class Employee(CreateView):
    fields = ('name','company')
    model = models.Employee

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        comp_name = self.request.POST.get("company", "")
        shop_id = ""            

        for word in dept_name.split(" "):
            shop_id += word[:1]

        self.object.nik = shop_id[-3:]
        self.object.save()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

iam trying to get value from ForeignKey on my code `self.request.POST.get("company", "")` is return `id` of the company, i need its return the `company.name`. how do that?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be accessing `request.POST`; the point of the form is that it converts the posted data into the correct format, in this case the ForeignKey.

Here, the company will already be stored on the object as a result of `form.save`; you should access it there:

```
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    comp_name = self.object.company.name
```

Comment: when I change it to `comp_name = self.object.company` I got error `'Company' object has no attribute 'split'`